# Conditional formatting for current day date

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am just trying to getting my data to do a color fill if the date value equals today.

The data is coming from oracle:

```
=IIf(Fields!finishDATE.Value = Today(),"Yellow","Transparent")
```

This will not give me any errors nor will it do the function according to the expression.  None of the data with the finish date equaling today highlights.

If today is 8/24/2021 it should look like this:

3/22/2021, ***8/24/2021***, 2/22/2021

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm not sure what format the data will come in from Oracle (I'm a MS SQL person) then this might be overkill but try this

```
=IIF (Format(Fields!finishDATE.Value, "yyyyMMdd") = Format(Today(), "yyyyMMdd"), "Yellow", Nothing)
```

All I'm doing here is comparing just the date parts of the date/datetime values.

Below is the output. The first column is the actual date column contents including a time, then for illustration only, the 2nd column shows it formatted to just the date part and the 3rd column show today() with the same format applied.

[image]

Finally, I used the keyword `Nothing` (SSRS almost equivalent of NULL) as this is the correct default value.